# Adding to sceneGroup within a function?

Tags: coronasdk

This is an issue I come up against time and time again. I just can't get my head round it. This code was under create scene now I want to put it in a function with the idea of generated these blocks at different locations automatically through a loop. The errors I get are: 
bad argument #1 in newRect (number expected) - 1st line.
sceneGroup is a nil value.

The solutions I have tried are:
1) defining sceneGroup at top of script. But then I get error that upvalue is a nil value. 
2) defining it immediately before. - nil value.

If someone could explain this to me I would be very grateful. I keep getting problems like this.

```
local Backgroundrectangle = display.newRect(sceneGroup, 75, 75, display.contentWidth-150, display.contentHeight/2 )
Backgroundrectangle.isVisible = false
Backgroundrectangle.anchorX = 0
Backgroundrectangle.anchorY = 0

 aAbackground = display.newRoundedRect(sceneGroup, Backgroundrectangle.x, Backgroundrectangle.y, 100, 125, 10 )
sceneGroup:insert(aAbackground)
aAbackground.id = "a"
aAbackground.strokeWidth = 2
aAbackground:setFillColor( gradient )
aAbackground:setStrokeColor( 0.2 )
aAmenutext = display.newText( "Aa", 100, 200, "Comic Sans MS", 50)
aAmenutext.x = aAbackground.x
aAmenutext.y = aAbackground.y - aAbackground.height/6
aAmenutext:setFillColor( 0.2 )
sceneGroup:insert(aAmenutext)
```

Comment: [Introducing the Composer API](https://coronalabs.com/blog/2014/01/21/introducing-the-composer-api-plus-tutorial/) and [Tutorial: Understanding the Composer API](https://coronalabs.com/blog/2014/06/03/tutorial-understanding-the-composer-api/) are both sources of  useful information about using composer and scene group. I recommended you read it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Upvalue is nil" means the Runtime expects `sceneGroup` to be a local defined outside the scope of the function, but this is not the usual way of doing this in Corona.

If you have this

```
local composer = require( "composer" )
local scene = composer.newScene()
```

at the top of your Lua file for the scene, whenever you want to add a DisplayObject to the scene's GroupObject (possibly in your `scene:create()` method), you can declare

```
local sceneGroup = scene.view
```

and then use `sceneGroup` as you have been.  `scene` will be defined (it has file scope) and the `view` property gives you the scene's GroupObject.